# Как получить все элементы Grid view

Tags: java, android, adapter, gridview, recyclerview.adapter

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, как получить все элементы gridview . У меня в gridview находится матрица editText, записывалось через собственный адаптер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так, с кастомным Layout должно сработать:

```
int childCount = yourAdapter.getChildCount();
for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
   View childView = yourAdapter.getChildAt(i);
}
```